# program to check whether point lies on x-axis , y-axis or origin

Tags: c

I have just started learning c programming.

For the question, I wrote the following code. Can you please help me find the error? I  am not getting the desired result and the statement in the last else gets executed always.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void dummy(float *a) 
{
  float b=*a; //perform some floating access
  dummy (&b); //calling a floating point function
}

void main()
{
  double x,y;

  clrscr();

  scanf("%lf %lf",x,y);

  if(x==0 && y!=0)
  { 
    printf("The point lies on the y-axis.");
  }
  else if(y==0 && x!=0 )
  { 
    printf("The point lies on the x-axis.");
  }
  else if(x==0 && y==0)
  { 
    printf("The point is the origin");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("The point lies neither on the x nor the y axis ");
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include input that causes the faulty behavior, as well as the actual and expected output.

Comment: hi. whatever be the 2 numbers i enter ,the statement"the point lies neither on the x nor the y axis" gets executed

Comment: tht's what must happen when you don;t  check the return value of scanf.

Comment: return value of scanf?

Comment: Never compare floating point values directly for (un)equality: like it's said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858547/8051589. This may could be the problem.

Comment: thanks andre. but it's still not working

Comment: hey andre. i used fabs with both the inequality and the equality cases earlier. but now i used it only with the inequality case and the code works. Thanks

Comment: It's fortunate you don't use the dummy function since it leads to a crash because it recurses indefinitely.  It shouldn't be in the question though. Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while reading values from keyboard with `scanf` you need to add `&` infront of variable.

instead

```
scanf("%lf %lf",x,y);
```

Use

```
scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);
```

**Update**

you dont have to check every time for both `y` and `x`

instead `if(x==0 && y!=0)` use only one, `if(x==0)` or `if(y==0)` Try:

```
void main()
{
   double x,y;
   clrscr();

   scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);

   if(x==0 && y==0)
   { 
       printf("points lies on origin.");
   }
   else if(y==0)
   { 
       printf("points lies on y-axis.");
   }
   else if(x==0)
   { 
       printf("points lies on x-axis");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("The point lies neither on the x nor the y axis ");
   }
   getch();
}
```

Comment: check my answer now, you need to check only `x==0` or `y==0` at a time

Answer (score 1):

For to check if is equal use macro or function like

```
#define FEQUAL(x,y,err)            (fabs((x) - (y)) < (err))
```

Answer (score 1):

Undefined reference to clrscr() function. So, you can try removing clrscr() function from your code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void dummy(float *a)
{
  float b=*a; //perform some floating access
  dummy (&b); //calling a floating point function
}

void main()
{
  double x,y;
  scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);

  if(x==0 && y!=0)
 {
    printf("The point lies on the y-axis.");
 }
  else if(y==0 && x!=0 )
 {
    printf("The point lies on the x-axis.");
 }
  else if(x==0 && y==0)
 {
    printf("The point is the origin");
 }
  else
 {
    printf("The point lies neither on the x nor the y axis ");
 }
    getch();
 }
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution may be as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the point ");
    scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y);
    if (y==0)
    {
        if (x==0)
        {
            printf("\nPonit lies on the origin\n");
        }
        else
            printf("\nPoint lies on X-axis\n");
    }
    else if (x==0)
    {
        if (y==0)
        {
            printf("\nPoint lies on the origin\n");
        }
        else
            printf("\nPoint lies on the Y-axis\n");
    }
    else
        printf("\nPoint lies in X-Y coordinate\n");
    return 0;
}
```